# How to handle better chained thens?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

Hello in ionic3 app I have code depending on 2 providers `getChildren` and `getBottle` - which ones return promises. I would like to make this code clean, however I need to use 2 providers in order to handle data from API. Thanks for any suggestions.

```js
this.dayReportProvider.getChildren(this.groupId, this.dateFromDailyOverview)
      .then((val: any) => {
        this.fetchedChildren = val.mobile_employee_getactive_children_of_day.map(item => item);
        this.fetchedChildren.forEach((item, i) => {
          this.fetchedChildren[i].color = "secondary"
        })
        return this.fetchedChildren;
      })
      .then((fetchedChildren) => {
        console.log('second then fetchedChildren =>', this.fetchedChildren)
        // calling the second Provider
        return this.getBottle();
      })
      .then((preselectedChildren) => {
        console.log('third then after getBottle() preselectedChildren', preselectedChildren);
        this.preselectedChildren = preselectedChildren;
          this.fetchedChildren = this.fetchedChildren.map((el) => {
            if (this.preselectedChildren.includes(Number(el.id))) {
              return {
                ...el,
                color: 'primary'
              }
            }
            return el;
          });
          // Make preselectedChildren available for submit
          this.selectedChildren = this.fetchedChildren.filter((child) => {
            return child.color === "primary";
          }) 

        if (this.navParams.data.childId) {
          this.childId = this.navParams.data.childId;
          this.selectChildBasedOnParams();
        }
        this.appFunctionCtrl.dismissLoader();
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log('Errror with fetching children', err))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some sugestions:
First of all, you can extract your code into the smaller functions. Quick example for first 'then'.

```
changeColor = () => {
   this.fetchedChildren = val.mobile_employee_getactive_children_of_day.map(item => item);
   this.fetchedChildren.forEach((item, i) => {
       this.fetchedChildren[i].color = "secondary"
   })
   return this.fetchedChildren;
}
```

In some places, you can use ES6 advanced features, to make code shorter:

```
this.selectedChildren = this.fetchedChildren.filter((child) => child.color === "primary")
```

You can also move out your code in map, filter and forEach methods outside, into the constants and use this code also in other places.

```
this.selectedChildren = this.fetchedChildren.filter(filterByColor()) 

filterByColor = () => child => child.color === "primary"
```

Is also an good idea to create enum for colors.

If you do so complicated operations inside Angular app, I suppose to use RXJS.

Answer (score 2):

I'd start by using async/await to flatten things out a bit, then chain the map/filter into a single operation to get  rid of the intermediate assignment. This would give you something like:

```
try {

    const val = await dayReportProvider.getChildren(groupId, dateFromDailyOverview)

    const fetchedChildren = val.mobile_employee_getactive_children_of_day.map(item => item)
    fetchedChildren.forEach((item, i) => {
        fetchedChildren[i].color = "secondary"
    })

    console.log("second then fetchedChildren =>", fetchedChildren)
    // calling the second Provider
    const preselectedChildren = await getBottle()
    console.log("third then after getBottle() preselectedChildren", preselectedChildren)
    const selectedChildren = fetchedChildren
        .map(el => {
            if (preselectedChildren.includes(Number(el.id))) {
                return {
                    ...el,
                    color: "primary"
                }
            }
            return el
        })
        .filter(child => {
            return child.color === "primary"
        })

    if (navParams.data.childId) {
        childId = navParams.data.childId
        selectChildBasedOnParams()
    }
    appFunctionCtrl.dismissLoader()
} catch (err) {
    console.log("Errror with fetching children", err)
}
```

Kamil Naja reply covers other sensible ideas to simplifying the map/filters